# Elliptic theory on compact manifolds

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, elliptic-pde, regularity

Maybe this is silly.

On a bounded set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ consider the equation

$$ \Delta u=f \quad\text{ in $\Omega$}$$
$$ u=0\quad\text{ on $\partial\Omega$}.$$

One has the following elliptic estimates

$$ \| u\|_{W^{2,p}}\le C\|f\|_{L^p}. $$

Does one can have the same result if instead of $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ one consider the same problem in a compact Riemannian manifold with boundary?
I know that one has

$$\|u\|_{W^{2,p}}\le C(\|f\|_{L^p}+\|u\|_{L^p}) $$

for the general case.. is it true that one can get rid of $\| u\|_{L^p}$ considering zero boundary conditions?

This should be true using a covering argument and the result in $\mathbb{R}^n$ but I cannot find anything in literature. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Use a relatively open cover of the manifold and a partition of unity subordinate to this cover to write $u$ as a sum of functions that each satisfy the Dirichlet problem.

Comment: When you want to prove elliptic regularity estimates on compact manifolds, it is easier to start with the estimates that bound the norm of $u$ on a ball in terms of weaker norms of u and f  on a larger ball. (In this case, $u$ satisfies the equation on the larger ball, and there is no boundary condition assumed.)

Comment: @BrettParker: could you please say something more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the case of a sphere. The boundary is empty. A constant $u$ satisfies the equation with $f=0$. You cannot get rid of the $u$ on the right hand side of the inequality in this case.

EDIT: I think this example demonstrates the difficulty of trying to use only local estimates pieced together with partitions of unity to eliminate $u$ on the right hand side of the inequality.

On the other hand, a possible strategy for proving the inequality without $u$ in the right hand side could be the following:

- Note that the Laplace-Beltrami operator with Dirichlet boundary conditions is (essentially) self-adjoint on, say the domain of $u$ in $W^{2,2}$ vanishing at the boundary, and the spectrum is discrete (by compactnesss)
- A maximum principle shows that if the boundary is nonempty (and manifold connected), then $0$ is not an eigenvalue. This is the essential global ingredient.
- The resolvent $\Delta^{-1}$ at $0$ is bounded in $L^2$, which means that we can eliminate $u$ in the right hand side of the inequality for $p=2$.
- We might be able to proceed by interpolation to general $p$.

Comment: A sphere you mean a manifold without boundary? I mean when i can prescribe boundary conditions. It is clear that without boundary you cannot get rid of the u in the rhs, it is like considering the problem with non homogeneus boundary conditions on an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: My point was that elimination of u on the rhs needs to utilize. some global property of the manifold, like no components with empty bdry. In facts elimination of u on rhs implies uniqueness of the Dirichlet problem.

Comment: @NJK: though your counterexample can be easily cured if the OP assumes his manifold to be connected.

Comment: @NJK: why it implies uniqueness for the dirichlet problem? Do you have a reference

Comment: The inequality w/o u on the rhs implies that if f=0, then u=0. By linearity, if u_1 and u_2 solves the Dirichlet problem with the same f, then || u_1 - u_2 ||_{W^{2,p}} <= 0, and so u_1 = u_2. (My apologies for missing formatting)

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer replaced by new one:

Fix a finite relatively open
cover $U_1, \dots, U_m$ of $M$, where
each $U_i$ is diffeomorphic to either the open ball 
or the half-ball obtained by intersecting the open ball with a closed
half-space. Let $\phi_1, \dots, \phi_N$ be a partition of unity
subordinate to this cover.

If $u$ satisfies
$$
\Delta u = f\text{ and }u = 0\text{ on }\partial M,
$$
then
$$
\Delta(\phi_iu) = \phi_if + \Delta\phi_iu + 2\nabla\phi\cdot\nabla u.
$$
If the support of $\phi_i$ is contained in an open ball, then
$\phi_iu$ vanishes on the boundary. If the support of $\phi_i$ is
contained in the half-ball, then $\phi_i u$ vanishes on
the boundary of the half-ball, because $u$ is assumed to be zero on
$\partial M$. Therefore, by the estimate for the Dirichlet problem and
the Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality,
\begin{align*}
\|\phi_iu\|_{2,p}
&\le C_1(\|f\|_p  + \|u\|_p + \|\nabla u\|_p)\\
&\le C_2(\|f\|_p + \|u\|_p +
2\|\nabla^2u\|_p^{1/2}\|u\|_p^{1/2})\\
&\le C_2(\|f\|_p + \|u\|_p +
\epsilon\|\nabla^2u\|_p + \epsilon^{-1}\|u\|_p).
\end{align*}
Set $\epsilon = 1/(2NC_2)$. Adding everything up, we get
\begin{align*}
\|u\|_{2,p} &=\|\sum_i \phi_iu\|_{2,p} \le \sum_i \|\phi_iu\|_{2,p}\\
&\le C_2N(\|f\|_p + (1+2NC_2)\|u\|_p) + \frac{1}{2}\|u\|_{2,p}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$
\|u\|_{2,p} \le C(\|f\|_p + \|u\|_p).
$$

Comment: After using the partition of unity, the right hand side of the Dirichlet problem is something like 

$$ \Delta\varphi_i  u+f\varphi_i+\nabla\varphi_i\nabla u $$
where $\varphi_i$ is the partition of unity related to a finite covering of $M$. I end up again with some term depending on $u$, how to get rid of that? that was the issue in the first place..

Comment: I am sorry Deane, never used this trick. Still cannot see how the norm of $u$ disappears. You say add and subtract in the first inequality you wrote but Then i am left on the rhs with something like $$ C\| u\|_p+\tilde C\varepsilon^{-1}\| u\|_p + \varepsilon \|\nabla^2 u\|_p +C\| f\|_p$$

Comment: Sorry. What I said isn't quite right.

Comment: I am sorry Deane but still this is not so clear. I have
$$ \|u\|_{2,p}-\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla^2 u\|_p=\|u\|_p+\|\nabla u\|_p+\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla^2 u\|_p $$
if you multiply by two you have that this is equal to
$$\|u\|_{2,p}+2(\|u\|_p+2\|\nabla u\|_p) $$
After subtracting the term $\frac{1}{2}\|\nabla^2u\|_p$ and multipy by two in the rhs of your last equation you have
$$ 2CN(\|f\|_p+\varepsilon^{-1}\|u\|_p)$$
Putting toghether you're left with
$$ \|u\|_{2,p}\le 2CN(\|f\|_p+\varepsilon^{-1}\|u\|_p)-2(\|u\|_p+\|\nabla u\|_p)$$
And where did you use the homogeneous boundary cdts?

Comment: I will post a more detailed proof when I find the time, but I encourage you to try to figure out how to put all the pieces together yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your time Deane. This proof was clear. My point in the question wasn't this estimate though. I was asking if it is possible to get rid of the last term, namely $\|u\|_p$, since i am considering the problem on a manifold with boundary and i am imposing homogeneous boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

For the specific question of getting rid of the low-order term $\|u\|_p$, what you really need is the compact embedding of $W^{2,p}$ in $L^p$ ([Rellich–Kondrachov theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rellich%E2%80%93Kondrachov_theorem)). Indeed, suppose there is no bound $\|u\|_{2,p}\le C\|f\|_p$, then there is a sequence $u_n$ such that $\|u_n\|_{2,p}=1$ and $\|f_n\|_p\to 0$, where $f_n=\Delta u_n$. By the compact embedding, we can pass to a subsequence so that $u_n$ converges in $L^p$. Combining this with $f_n\to 0$ in $L^p$, we know $u_n$ converges in $W^{2,p}$. Let $u$ be the limit, then $u$ would be a nonzero function whose Laplacian is zero, which is impossible by your boundary conditions.

Comment: This uses that the boundary is non-empty. If the boundary is empty, then there exist nonzero functions whose Laplacian is zero, namely constant functions. This is the counter-example from NJK's answer. It is not clear to me if the question allows for empty boundary or not, but your answer and NJK's answer together cover both possibilities. (This is no criticism of your answer, it's just writing something down that I hope may help others be less confused about this subject.)